# How to use ` ` in c#

Tags: c#, console-application

I want to add ASCII art to a c# console application this doesn't work.

in javascript, I can do this

`` console.log(` hey `) ``

but I can't do the same in c#

`` console.WriteLine(` hey `) ``

what should I do?

edit:

I want to be able to do this

```
Console.WriteLine(`
hello :))
:]

`)
```

Comment: C# requires string to be enclosed in double quotes (`" hey "`) rather than backticks (`\` hey \``).

Comment: You mean double quotes?

Comment: console.WriteLine(" ` hey ` ")

Comment: If you want to do multi-line strings in C# you have to put an @ before the opening quote: ``string str = @"multi line string goes here";``

Answer (score 0):

chose what you want

```
Console.WriteLine(" hey ")
//will print:  hey

Console.WriteLine("` hey `")
//will print: ` hey `
```